# Use reference from another project at the same solution

Tags: c#, reference, projects-and-solutions

I have a c# solution with a number of projects. One project, is sort of a tool for the others let us call it `tool`. It is compiled into `tool.dll` which in turn is referenced in other projects in the solution (project A and B for example). Inside `tool` project I  have a reference to an external dll, `foo.dll`.

If I need to use methods that are defined in `foo.dll` inside project A, can I do it via the reference to `tool.dll`? I know I can add `foo.dll` to each project, but than if it has a new version I need to update it manually for each project and that is what I am trying to avoid.

In general, I want to avoid adding `foo.dll` to each project and somehow add it to only one place and share it. If it is at all possible, Is there another way to go about it?

I dont know if it is of any importance, but I am using visual studio 2010 with .NET framework 4.

Comment: You can write interface in tool.dll that will share methods from foo.dll to the rrst od your system.

Answer (score 1):

You could place `foo.dll` in a central place (location on disk, like `C:\Tools\foo.dll`) and reference the same file from each project.

To prevent having to manually update the references for every update, you could try wrapping `foo.dll` in a nuget package (if it's not available on NuGet.org already). That way you can let nuget handle the updates.

Comment: What would be called a central place? I tried working with the `tool` project as sort of my central place.